# Simple React/Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I am just starting to play around with express and react and am having issues with the simplest of projects. Could anyone take a peek and let me know what I might be missing?

*server.js*

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.listen(3000);
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>React Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <script src="test.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*test.js*

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var TEST = require('./test');

window.React = React;

var MainComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <TEST/>
        );
    }
});
```

*test.js*

```
import React from 'react';

var TEST = React.createClass ({
    render: function() {
        return (<div>Hello World</div>);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
   <MainComponent />
   document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: You need to link to the index.js script in your html file with a <script> tag, and make sure you are able to serve the index.js file from your express app.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you're missing a comma between the component and where you want to render it. See corrected:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <MainComponent />,
   document.getElementById('app')
);
```